# Programmatically segue..works ever

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to create a manual segue, which happens only if there is a certain conidition (a successful login).

The steps I have followed are these:

**1)** I've created a button in source viewcontroller, and i connected the button with a drag with the destination viewcontroller.

**2)** I set the identifier for the segue, calling it `login_ok`

**3)** I've created a `-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender`

Now, I tried to make an example, to see if the work or not. I wrote:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    BOOL test = false;
    if(test == true)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_ok" sender:self];
    }
```

Theoretically, the segue should `not` work, because i set `test=false`, and i said the segue should work only if test=true.

**But** the segue works and makes me go to the destination viewcontroller.

Why?

Comment: How did you create the segue? In storyboard? Did you drag it from the button to the destination vc or from the first vc?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth yep, I've created a segue in storyboard. I have selected the button in the source viewcontroller and I dragged it to the destination viewcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you connected the button with a drag to the destination controller, it should segue anyway.

You need to connect the segue between screens and not from the button to the screen. Then, you can control your segue from the code.

Comment: Thanks for attributing :)

Answer (score 0):

You should define your segue between controllers not from button to the controller. Defining segue between view controllers is more useful than defining segue from any component to a view controller, because when you want to use a condition for any action, you can use these two methods effectively

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueID" sender:self];`

and

`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`

For example:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    BOOL test = YES;
    if(test == YES)
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_ok" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"login_ok"])
   {
       YourNextController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];

       controller.welcomeText = @"Hi! Test is true congratulations";
   }
}
```

Especially passing data from controller to another one, this way is always useful.